# Destroying python object after removing it from list of objects

Tags: python-3.x

I have an object:

```
class Flow:
```

this object belongs to list of objects `flowList = [Flow1, Flow2, Flow3]`

If I do:

```
del flowList[0]
```

Do I need to destroy as well Flow1 object? I want my script to process thousands of flows and be memory efficient. Processed flow should die after processing as it won't be needed anymore.

Comment: I processed some bigger data sets (like > 20 TB on regular bases). It was OCR, image processing, natural language processing thing.  I never bothered deleting anything explicitly. Just do not point to the value once you do not need it. Once nothing is pointing to that object it should be removed and usually it works very well. https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/#:~:text=Reference%20counting%20is%20a%20simple,to%20the%20right%2Dhand%20side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not required, and there [are no reliable ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python) that I know of of explicitly freeing certain memory anyways.

Python uses Garbage Collection, which means it automatically disposes of objects when they are no longer needed. Once you're done with an object, you can simply leave it. If the only reference to `Flow1` was the one inside the list, `del flowList[0]` is sufficient to allow it to be freed. If there's another reference outside of the list, you can do `del Other_Flow1` to delete the other reference to allow it to be freed.

---

If you have something like this:

```
huge_list = [1, 2, 3, . . .]
use_huge_list(huge_list)
```

You could add something like this after the call to `use_huge_list` to help free `huge_list` more readily:

```
del huge_list
```

This deletes the reference `huge_list` to the `[1, 2, 3, . . .]` object. If that's the only reference to the object, it will allow it to be freed. I'd only do this though if memory is a huge concern, and `huge_list` will remain in scope for an extended period of time, but is never used (although, that may be a smell that suggests that you need to refactor anyway).

---

I would not use `del` like that constantly though. It's unnecessary to delete labels in 99% of cases. Don't overthink it. Unless you've profiled and know for sure that objects staying in memory are causing you problems, don't worry about it.